# OpenGL rendering looks squeezed

Tags: opengl, camera, opentk

I am rendering bunch of cubes of unit size, but for some reason they look like they are squeezed a bit in the screen-space y axis. Why is this?

My projection matrix:

```
Projection = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView (fovy, width / height, zNear, zFar);
```

My view matrix:

```
View = Matrix4.LookAt (position, position + Direction, up);
```

My Model matrix:

```
Matrix4 modelMatrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(chunkPos.X * 32, chunkPos.Y * 32, chunkPos.Z * 32));
```

Here's how I form the MVP matrix:

```
ViewProjection = View * Projection;
ModelViewProjection = Model * ViewProjection;
```

And finally the vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = mMVP * vertex;
```

Screenshots displaying the problem:

[image: Squeezed Y-axis in screen-space]
[image: Squeezed Y-axis in screen-space]

I tried to fix the problem by adding a y-axis scale of 1.5 to my View matrix, and it seems it helped a bit with the problem. The result:

[image]

### The question

I want to understand why I have to scale it this way. I thought the aspect ratio I give to the CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView would do this correction for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And literally 1min after I post the question I found out the answer. The problem was that on my projection matrix creation the width and height are integers, and thus the aspect ratio would be always 1. I changed the width and height to floats, and it started working.

Comment: Glad you found your answer. Asking the question by itself usually leads to more clarity into the problem at hand. [This story](https://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html) comes to mind.